# Android - How to use different code lines depending of Android version

Tags: android, android-version

I have a project which is compatible with Android versions from 10(GINGERBREAD_MR1) to 17(JELLY_BEAN_MR1).

So, I would like to use `setBackgroundDrawable` for versions lower to 16 and `setBackground` from version 16 or upper.

I've tried this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    subMessageFromToLinearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
} else {
    subMessageFromToLinearLayout.setBackground(null);
}
```

But, Eclipse gives me:

A warning for `subMessageFromToLinearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(null);`:
*"The method setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) from the type View is deprecated"*

And an error for `subMessageFromToLinearLayout.setBackground(null);`:
*"Call requires API level 16 (current min is 10): android.widget.LinearLayout#setBackground"*

How can I fix this errors in order I can use both lines depending of the running Android version?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you set the target to 16+? The warning is a non-issue. I assume you can not build the project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general the most robust way makes use of [class lazy loading](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html):

```
static boolean isSDK17()
{
   return android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1;
}


if (isSDK17())
    xyMode_SDK17.setXyMode(context, mode);
else
    xyMode_SDK8.setXyMode(context, mode);


@TargetApi(17)
public class xyMode_SDK17
{
  static void setXyMode(Context context, boolean mode)
  {...}
}


public class xyMode_SDK8
{
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  static void setXyMode(Context context, boolean mode)
   {...}
}
```

Comment: Yes, I added the annotations `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)`and `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`and that let me compile. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen

[ActionBarSherlock gives tons of "Call requires API level 11 (current min is 7)" errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260801/actionbarsherlock-gives-tons-of-call-requires-api-level-11-current-min-is-7)

[Android - set layout background programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678949/android-set-layout-background-programmatically)

You can mark it with @TargetApi(16) and @SuppressWarnings("deprecated").

If the error still there, try cleaning the project or restart eclipse.

> "ah I know of the .setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) method but to me the IDE had the same error with api 16 requirement. I am using Eclipse and it seemed to be a bug after reopening the ide and cleaning the code a bit it worked. Than you very much and sorry for trouble".